# Unable to access installed certificate on Build Server using C# code

Tags: c#, build-server, certificate-store

Unable to access Certificate using `C#` code. The Certificate has been installed on Build Server. I am accessing the certificate using below code which doesn't work in my case:

```
public static X509Certificate2 FindCertificateByThumbprint(string findValue)
{
    X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
    try
    {
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        X509Certificate2Collection col = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, findValue, false);
        log.Info("X509Certificate2Collection col count : " + col.Count);
        log.Info(col.Count == 0 ? "Could not find the certificate" : "Certificate Retrieved");
        if (col == null || col.Count == 0)
            return null;
        return col[0];
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        log.Info(ex.StackTrace.ToString());
        log.Info(ex.Message);
        log.Info(ex.InnerException);
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        store.Close();
    }
}
```

The `X509Certificate2Collection` col count is returned as 0. While I debug the code on build server I am able to retrieve the certificate. But unable to retrieve the same from local machine.

`StackTrace` @ col.Count:

```
at System.Collections.CollectionBase.System.Collections.IList.get_Item(Int32 index)
at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection.get_Item(Int32 index)
```

Thank you

Comment: I am having this situation running on an Azure Function. Did you resolve this?

Comment: never mind, figured it out. Turns out in an Azure Function you have to specifiy the certs you want your app to load - even if they are already in the Azure Cert store